# Problem with creating a 2D matrix of characters

Tags: c++, char

I've been trying many different ways to create a 2D matrix from data input from a text file. However, every way I try I keep running into errors. The method in the code below is the one that has the least errors but still I get an error on the return object saying that I am using uninitialized memory 'matrix'. Apologies is if this is a simple fix, I'm very new to C++.

I've previously tried vectors of vectors but ran into the issue of getting wrong dimensions. If anyone has a better way to create a matrix of characters from a text file, please let me know!

```
char** GetMap(int& M, int& N) //function to get the map of a room
{

    int M = 0; // initializing rows variable
    int N = 0; // initializing columns variable
    char** matrix; //give a matrix

    cin >> M >> N;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me tell you that you are asking for `M` and `N` in `std::cin` input but you already have them as parameters of your function `char** GetMap(int& M, int& N)`.

Now, you will probably **need** to use `std::vector` in your case. In fact, you want to initialize your `char** matrix` with your two variables M and N, which is not allowed in proper C++.

A good way to solve this problem is to use an `std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix` instead of a  `char** matrix`. Here's a solution which will do what you expect

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> GetMap(int& M, int& N) //function to get the map of a room
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix{}; //give a matrix
    char char_buf;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < M; rows++)
    {
        matrix.push_back(std::vector<char>()); //Put a new empty row in your matrix
        for (int cols = 0; cols < N; cols++)
        {
            std::cin >> char_buf; //Here you get a char from std::cin
            matrix.back().push_back(char_buf); //That you push back in your sub-vector
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This seems to have fixed the problem.